# Amplify flutter authentication

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify

I am trying to implement Amplify in my flutter project. I wanna to get userSub just after signing up a new user without login and account verify. I am using email as a username.
Some others suggested to use `Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()` but I think I can't use this method without login.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement authentication after you can get user data. Check the [Documentation from Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/signin/q/platform/flutter#register-a-user)

**SignUp**

```
try {
  Map<String, String> userAttributes = {
    'email': 'email@domain.com',
    'phone_number': '+15559101234',
    // additional attributes as needed
  };
  SignUpResult res = await Amplify.Auth.signUp(
    username: 'myusername',
    password: 'mysupersecurepassword',
    options: CognitoSignUpOptions(
      userAttributes: userAttributes
    )
  );
  setState(() {
    isSignUpComplete = res.isSignUpComplete;
  });
} on AuthException catch (e) {
  print(e.message);
}
```

**ConfirmSignUP**

```
try {
  SignUpResult res = await Amplify.Auth.confirmSignUp(
    username: 'myusername',
    confirmationCode: '123456'
  );
  setState(() {
    isSignUpComplete = res.isSignUpComplete;
  });
} on AuthException catch (e) {
  print(e.message);
}
```

**SignIn**

```
try {
  SignInResult res = await Amplify.Auth.signIn(
    username: usernameController.text.trim(),
    password: passwordController.text.trim(),
  );
  setState(() {
    isSignedIn = res.isSignedIn;
  });
} on AuthException catch (e) {
  print(e.message);
}
```

Follow this [video tutoril](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blkbaOLvruQ&list=PL5h37q2DJtAP36eI9j9yKxbZBASUMb9eZ&index=20&t=108s) you can implement Amplify Auth using BLOC architecture

Comment: Thank you, I already followed that general integration way, now wanna to get the user sub just after signing in, please focus on the question :)